# Initializing culerity with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd, celerity, culerity

I want to initialize culerity with capybara in ruby 1.9 i followed https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/culerity/ for jruby integration of culerity and added below line to my features/support/env.rb file

`Culerity.jruby_invocation = File.expand_path("~/.rvm/bin/celerity_jruby")`

added follwing lines to my Gemfile,

```
gem 'culerity'
gem 'celerity', :require => false
```

wheni run my cucumber test case, i got this error

```
 no driver called :culerity was found, available drivers: :rack_test, :selenium (Capybara::DriverNotFoundError)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work after a some trouble, it would seem that culerity works with ruby 1.9 despite capybara's notes still saying otherwise. However, culerity support has been separated into another gem "capybara-culerity".

There were rumours support would be dropped from capybara back in Feb (source google groups), I guess this solution allows a third-party(s) to keep the support alive. ryansch's solution is basically correct, however, there are a few additional requirements to get things working.

I have outlined the steps below, assuming that the steps in the RVM tutorial have been implmented correctly (https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/culerity/ ), that is, gemsets, symbolic links, rvm, rvm wrapper, JRuby and Bash environment etc

***Steps***

**Install the capybara-culerity gem**

**For celerity's Jruby environment ...** (make sure celerity_jruby points to jruby, I pointed to the symbolic link under jruby@celerity)

```
>> celerity_jruby -S gem install capybara-culerity
```

**For your projects main ruby environment add following to the gemfile and bundle install**

Gemfile

```
... cucumber etc  ...
gem 'capybara' 
gem 'capybara-culerity'
gem 'culerity' 
gem 'celerity', :require => nil # jruby only
```

...

```
>>bundle install
```

**add the following to your features/support/env.rb**

```
require 'capybara/culerity'
```

...

```
Capybara.register_driver :culerity do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Culerity.new(app)
end
```

...

```
Culerity.jruby_invocation = File.expand_path("~/.rvm/bin/celerity_jruby")
```

**then in features/support/capybara.rb** ...  I suppose it could go in the env.rb instead

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :culerity  # celerity through culerity for JS 
Capybara.default_driver = :rake-text # non-JS eg rake-test
```

I hope this helps others.

Andrew (@andicrook)

Answer (score 0):

Add `capybara-culerity` to your Gemfile and try adding:

```
Capybara.register_driver :culerity do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Culerity.new(app)
end
```

to your features/support/env.rb file before the call to

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :culerity
```